# Chrome Extension: Remove body attributes from content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom

**This is not a duplicate... it is a continuation**

I am having a problem with removing attributes from the body tag from within a Chrome Extension. I have read quite a lot about this but I am still having problems.

Take the following body element:

```
<body onbeforeunload="bye()" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0">
```

I want to remove the `onbeforeunload` event completely. I can inject my script into the page but it still fails to remove the event; although it does run. So the problem is purely with the injected script removing the event.

This is the injected script.

```
document.write('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>');
console.log("onload called");
document.removeEventListener(onload);
document.removeEventListener(onmouseover);
document.removeEventListener(onbeforeunload);
var r = document.getElementById("body");
if (r !== null)
    console.log("Found Body");
$('body').onload.off();
$('body').onbeforeunload.off();
```

1. The document.write fails.
2. the console.log works.
3. The rest of the code fails.
4. $ is undefined.

Any assistance to get that attribute removed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing the JavaScript context from [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) and from the web page: they are different, but share the same DOM.
That's why the `$` is undefined, because it is inserted into web page, but it is used in content script.
What about just removing the attribute from body tag?

```
document.body.removeAttribute('onbeforeunload');
```